# Why does "tarrier" as an American job title not appear in OED or Merriam-Webster?

Tags: nouns, slang, north-american-english

The folksong "Drill Ye Tarriers Drill" is well-known:
[Wikipedia Drill Ye Tarriers Drill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill%2C_Ye_Tarriers%2C_Drill).

> The title refers to Irish workers, drilling holes in rock to blast out railroad tunnels. It may mean either to tarry as in delay, or to terrier dogs which dig their quarry out of the ground,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill%2C_Ye_Tarriers%2C_Drill) or from the French word for an augur, tarière.

But the word appears to be used in a different sense in Stephen Crane's "The Pace of Youth" (Crane, Stephen and Gado, Frank. Drawn from Life. Signature, 1997).

> "That young tarrier," he whispered to himself. "We wants to quit makin' eyes at Lizzie. This is too much of a good thing. First thing you know, he'll get fired."

In this context, the tarrier is a young man who works in an amusement park assisting with the merry-go-round. Clearly he's not drilling holes or laying railroad track.

Yet the Oxford English Dictionary on-line
[OED through VPN of Virginia Commonwealth University library](https://www-oed-com.proxy.library.vcu.edu/search?searchType=dictionary&q=tarrier&_searchBtn=Search)
recognizes no such sense of the word. Noun 1 is one who tarries; noun 2 is "A boring instrument, an auger; now, an instrument for extracting a bung from a barrel." Perhaps this is related to the railroad workers, who are drilling and driving stakes, I think.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tarrier) is even worse, bouncing immediately to the verb and also suggesting "tarry" means "covered with tar."

I am mystified that a well-known word—at least in American English—would not show up in either dictionary, when "navvy," for instance, shows up in the OED.

If "one who drills" is the only meaning besides "one who tarries," perhaps the use in the Crane story is obscene—meaning, "that boy who wants to do it to my daughter." But that seems a stretch?

Comment: Is it really "well-known"? Yes, I know the song, but I don't know of any other usage (aside from, now, the Crane passage).

Comment: Searching Google Books, limited to the 19th century, the first page of results all use the "tarrier" spelling to refer to dogs (aside from [this bewildering sketch](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Widow_Magoogin/tuQxAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22tarrier%22&pg=PA75&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22tarrier%22), which still seems to be somewhat dog-related, but also hints at an established and negative meaning especially in colloquial Irish usage.

Comment: I don't see how readers of this website can hope to explain the editorial decisions of individual dictionaries. Have you tried contacting the publishers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Crane story, the speaker may be comparing the young man to a (tenacious) terrier. It seems to have been a not-infrequent alternate spelling judging from Google Books.

How many times have we heard or read "If I catch you sniffing around my daughter"?

---

> "Seedy's a soft-spoken chap," Jake would say when the gang rehearsed
> his romance among themselves. "But he's a *tarrier* when he gits
> started."
> Sydow had to accept the absurd qualities in which they
> arrayed him, as he accepted the mantle of Mina's loving idealization.
> [*Short Stories from Outing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Short_Stories_from_Outing/FAVFAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22he%27s%20a%20tarrier%22) (1895, Italics in original)

Comment: How many times have we heard ... "If I catch you sniffing around my daughter"? - I heard it much more when I was younger than I do now.

Comment: A cold but honest assessment of our sense of smell.

Comment: Alluding as it does to female dogs on heat, and the resulting aroma emanating from a certain part of their anatomy, 'sniffing around' is liable to be considered extremely vulgar and insulting when used in connection with a female human .